How to calculate the eigenvectors of this matrix?
I have a matrix $A$ and I have calculated its eigenspace. I am curious about whether there is some property I am violating if I selected eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues in the following fashion:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-a&b\\a&-b-g\end{bmatrix}$$
Solving det$(A-I\lambda)=0$, I arrive at:
$$\lambda = \frac{-(a+b+g) \pm \left(\sqrt{\left(a+b+g\right)^2-4ag}\right)}{2}$$
Now, from the following equations:
$$(-a - \lambda_1)x + by = 0$$
$$ax +(-b-g-\lambda_1)y = 0$$
$$(-a - \lambda_2)x + by = 0$$
$$ax+(-b-g-\lambda_2)y=0$$
In theory I can arrive at different ways of expressing the eigenvectors, where $x_1=1$ and $y_1=(a+\lambda_1)/b$, and $x_2=1$ and $y_2=(a+\lambda_2)/b$, or I could write this another way, $x_1'=1$, $y_1'=a/(b+g+\lambda_1)$ and $x_2'=1$, $y_2'=a/(b+g+\lambda_2)$.
What if I selected $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2', y_2')$ as my eigenvectors for $A$? (As opposed to $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$?) Is this a basis error? Thank you in advance.

Yup. sorry - typo. Fixed

When you compute the eigenspace for an eigenvalue (say) $\lambda_1$, then you have to solve the system of equations $$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}-a-\lambda_1 & b&0\a&-b-g-\lambda_1&0\end{array}\right].$$ So, you need to find the common solution. What you are doing is just solving one equation at a time.

@AnuragA but I have two eigenvalues - so solving the system separately could yield (x1, y1) for $\lambda_1$ and (x2, y2) for $lambda_2$ or (x1, y1) and (x2', y2')?

There are multiple sets of eigenvectors depending on the values of $a$, $b$, and $g$. For example, if $b = 0,$ then $x \neq 1.$ This can be seen from the first equation: $(-a-\lambda_1)x + by = 0 \land b=0 \implies x = 0.$ Another case is when $b=g=0,$ which means that one of the eigenvalues is zero, which then means that $y=a/(b+g+\lambda)$ is no longer defined.
So, there are multiple sets of eigenvalues for this matrix. Each set depends on the values of $a$, $b$, and $g.$ As you solve the set of four equations to get the eigenvectors, pay attention to when you might be dividing by zero. Each time you split the set of solutions in two, one where the divisor is non-zero, and another where it is zero.
